# How can we perform an arithmetic operation on a register using GDB?

Tags: shell-script, c, binary, gdb, assembly

I want to inject a bit-flip fault into a running program. For this purpose, I'm using `gdb` to insert a breakpoint into the target program and then flipping a single bit in a random-selected register. When I perform this instruction under `gdb` in Ubuntu, I got this error when trying to manipulate `$eip`:

```
(gdb) info r
...
eip        0x804af59        0x804af59 <main+37>
...

(gdb) p/a $eip
$4 = 0x804af59 <main+37>

(gdb) set $eip = $eip ^ 0x800
argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean

(gdb) set $eax = $eax ^ 0x1
(gdb)
```

I can't realize is this a bug in GDB? or a syntax error.

The error only occurs when I try to change the following registers: `%eip`, `%esp`, and `%ebp`. As we can see from the listing, no problem occurs when I change the content of the `eax` register.

***More information...***

In safety critical systems that work in harsh environments, the system is more likely susceptible to soft error, i.e. Single Error Upset (**SEU**) like bit-flip. In this context, the researchers have been developed several techniques to detect such error and keep the system reliable, i.e., Fault-tolerance Techniques. In order to evaluate such techniques, the most powerful method is fault injection. You should inject fault to the most critical parts of architecture at run-time and then monitor the hardened system to assess the fault coverage of  the adopted fault-tolerance technique. Generally speaking, we should imitate soft errors using fault injection.
I quite understand the `eip` registrar what its job is and how sensitive it is to the control flow of the program.

The version of the used GDB is like follow:

```
gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Some output from the gdb session:

```
(gdb) p $eip
$1 = (void (*)()) 0x804af34 <main>

(gdb) ptype $eip
type = void (*)()
(gdb)
```

In addition, when I cast the `void` to `int`, it works without any error, ***but the result, I think, is not sound***, since I only try to toggle single bit by xoring the content of eip with 0x1  !!

```
(gdb) set $eip=*(int *) $eip ^ 0x1
(gdb) p $eip
$2 = (void (*)()) 0x4244c8c
```

the value of `eip` is **0x804af34**. So, if we perform a bitwise operation with **0x1**, the result should be equal to **0x804AF35** not **0x4244c8c** ?!

```
(gdb) p $eip
$8 = (void (*)()) 0x804af34 <main>
(gdb) p *(int *) ($eip)
$9 = 69487757
(gdb) p *(int *) $eip ^0x1
$10 = 69487756
(gdb) p/a *(int *) $eip ^0x1
$11 = 0x4244c8c
(gdb)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of `gdb --version`?

Comment: Also, are you aware of the purpose of the `eip` register?  It doesn't seem like what you're trying to do to it makes any sense.  That said, I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `(int)` to coerce the pointer to an int. And in your later tests you should **not** be using `*` to de-reference the pointer; you are fetching the memory that `$eip` points to.

```
(gdb) p/x (int)$eip  
$4 = 0xf7eb9810
(gdb) p/x (int)$eip^1
$5 = 0xf7eb9811
(gdb) set $eip = (int)$eip^1
(gdb) p/x (int)$eip
$6 = 0xf7eb9811
(gdb) set $eip = (int)$eip^0x800
(gdb) p/x (int)$eip
$7 = 0xf7eb9011
```